# Angular build - Expected identifier but found "*"

Tags: angular, typescript, sass, angular-cli, angular-builder

After upgrading to angular `13.0.0` this warning occur when building:

```
Warning:  > styles.a81eb7805197853d.css:10615:2: warning: Expected identifier but found "*"
    10615 │   *vertical-align: middle;
          ╵   ^
```

Why this happens?

`package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "wepod-clients",
  "version": "3.2.3",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node patch.js && ng serve",
    "serve-auth": "ng run wepod-app:serve-auth-standalone:production",
    "build": "node patch.js && node --max_old_space_size=8192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng run wepod-app:app-shell:production && ng run wepod-app:auth-standalone:production",
    "server": "npm run build && http-server -p 9090 -c-1 dist",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint --fix",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "postinstall": "node patch.js && ngcc",
    "postbuild": "node post-build.js",
    "prepare": "husky install",
    "build-latest": "git pull origin production && npm run build"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^13.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^13.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^13.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "^13.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^13.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^13.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^13.0.0",
    "@angular/localize": "^13.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^13.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^13.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^13.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^13.0.0",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^13.0.0",
    "@types/video.js": "^7.3.27",
    "animate.css": "^4.1.1",
    "assert": "^2.0.0",
    "bowser": "^2.11.0",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "bundle-loader": "^0.5.6",
    "compare-version": "^0.1.2",
    "constants-browserify": "^1.0.0",
    "crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "d3": "^6.5.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "https-browserify": "^1.0.0",
    "jalali-moment": "^3.3.10",
    "lottie-web": "^5.7.13",
    "lzutf8": "^0.6.0",
    "net": "^1.0.2",
    "ng-gallery": "^5.1.1",
    "ng2-jalali-date-picker": "^2.4.2",
    "ngx-device-detector": "^1.5.2",
    "ngx-doughnut-chart": "0.0.4",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^8.0.2",
    "ngx-lottie": "^7.0.4",
    "ngx-owl-carousel-o": "^3.1.1",
    "ngx-skeleton-loader": "^2.10.1",
    "ngx-toastr": "^12.1.0",
    "os-browserify": "^0.3.0",
    "podchat-browser": "^10.14.13",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.7",
    "stream-browserify": "^3.0.0",
    "stream-http": "^3.2.0",
    "tls": "0.0.1",
    "ts-ebml": "^2.0.2",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "video.js": "^7.15.4",
    "videojs-record": "^4.5.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^13.0.1",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^13.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^13.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^13.0.0",
    "@egjs/hammerjs": "^2.0.17",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.40",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.10",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.36",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "colors": "^1.4.0",
    "git-tag-version": "^1.3.1",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-gzip": "^1.4.2",
    "http-server": "^14.0.0",
    "husky": "^7.0.4",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "^6.3.7",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "^8.10.2",
    "tslint": "^6.1.3",
    "typescript": "4.4.4",
    "zip-dir": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "browser": {
    "fs": false,
    "path": false,
    "os": false
  }
}
```

For Instance, I provided a part of my `css` code below:

```
audio,
canvas,
video {
  display: inline-block;
  *display: inline;
  *zoom: 1;
}
```

I searched a lot. No outcome.

Comment: Can you post the styles.css file as well? According to the warning, something is wrong in your css file.

Comment: That is 15k lines of code @Raffael

Comment: lines 10600 - 10650 should be enough

Comment: I don't have access to the code right now but I have over 100 of this error and those lines are like this: "*display: block;" or like the error that I mentioned.

Comment: I just upgrade to Angular 13 and also got this weird error

Comment: I also got the same warning multiple times after upgrading to Angular 13.1.1

Comment: Still building with warnings. found no answer.

Comment: Possible use case for this: [Purpose of asterisk before a CSS property](/q/1690642/4642212). However, can you confirm whether or not this asterisk has always been there? You also don’t need to post 15k lines. A [mre] is enough.

Comment: I provided an example. @SebastianSimon

Comment: The way I read it : the * is a hack for older IE versions. Anguler no loger support IE so maybe tha is why it breaks. If you need to siupport IE, then maybe upgrading to 13 is not a good idea.

Comment: that's probably the answer. @Chai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular is removing support for IE 11.

There is 2 ways to confront that matter:

1. Remove support for IE 11 from `.browserslistrc` or `browserslist`:

```
last 1 Chrome version
last 1 Firefox version
last 2 Edge major versions
last 2 Safari major versions
last 2 iOS major versions
Firefox ESR
not IE 11 # Angular supports IE 11 only as an opt-in. To opt-in, remove the 'not' prefix on this line.
```

- `not` is essential.

2. Add support by compiling your project to lower ECMAScript by polyfills. You can follow the steps mentioned in [this article](https://www.bitovi.com/blog/ie-11-and-angular-overview.html).

Answer (score 0):

I had same as this problem too. I could resolve it by removing unnecessary style from Angular.json

```
"architect"
   "build"
     "options"
       "styles": [...]
```

Comment: Thank you Jalil but it's not really an answer. Maybe we should call it a a bad workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Like stated in this GitHub issue (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/22218) this warnings can occur if you do not even use the IE hack with the asterisk in your CSS files.

I had an old project with older dependencies which used the hack. I found them by searching for the CSS property with the asterisk in the generated CSS file. In one case a CSS class name next to the property hinted to the source. In another case a comment before the CSS part with the asterisk hack. In my case it was an outdated TinyMCE version and Bootstrap 3.4.1